# name of the file where InternalResourceViewResolver exists

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

[image]i am beginner to the spring mvc ,my question is regarding the file name where class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> exists . as i was going through online tutorials i found different names of the spring config file like spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml,spring-config.xml and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml ,so what is the default name and where do i have to mention this file whether in  web.xml or any other file?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be confusing for a newbie, in your web.xml you declare the servlet name and other details this can be any name(commonly known as dispatcher servlet) for the same name you create one more xml. you write it there.
like if the below file is your
 **web.xml**

```
<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Then you create a file called **dispatcher-servlet.xml** and write your code(view resolver etc) there .

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      ...(lot more that you need)>
     <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```

It changes with the name you have used in your web.xml.

Comment: CHECKK MY EDITED QUESTION ,THIS PROJECT WORKS FINE EVEN THOUGH THE NAME IS DIFFERENT AS YOU MENTIONED

Comment: i think i got now ,if i change the name then i have to mention the name in initparam thanx

Comment: you have added the init param tags which allows you to alter the name. try running it after commenting it(it should crash)

Answer (score 0):

They are usually defined in -sevlet.xml file..
In your case, it should be mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

You could overwrite it by specifying the init-param contextConfigLocation. However, in your case its commented that implies it defaults to mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml